How to prevent user from accessing navigation bar [PAX Device]
I am currently working on an Android Launcher app for a PAX device.
minSDK: 25
Theme: Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar
Manifest:
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ThemeName">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

I want to make sure that the user won't be able to leave the launcher app.
I tried setting flags on my MainActivity based on I found on related question: full screen application android
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

I also tried using WindowInsetsController
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =
                WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());

        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());

Both is hiding system bars(navigation & status bar), But if you swipe down or up, the system bars will show, I want it to be still hidden.
Do I need to use a specific theme & or manifest configuration to do this? or if not, how can I achieve this.
NOTE: I used a launcher app from our partner that does exactly what I needed. The navigation bar doesn't show, even if I swipe down or up; only the status bar is visible. However, swiping down does not display the quick settings panel.

"I want to make sure that the user won't be able to exit the launcher app." - A Launcher App, by virtue of being a Launcher App, is not "exited".
"if you swipe down or up, the system bars will show, I want it to be still hidden." - Why? What are you trying to actually achieve?

@dominicoder as mentioned above, I want to make sure that the user won't be able to exit the launcher app.

And as I mentioned in my comment, a launcher app isn't something you "exit". The system bars don't "exit" a launcher - they allow the user to navigate the UI. So, again, what are you actually trying to achieve by hiding the bottom navigation, given that the user already cannot "exit" the launcher?

This is a requirement of the project, user should not be able to leave the launcher app, by being able to access navigator bar, user will be able to go back to home or exit the app from recent apps. there will be an option to exit in the launcher app but have to enter a password.

"user will be able to go back to home" - what is "home", if not the launcher app? Maybe you're using different terms I'm not familiar with. AFAIK, "home" is the launcher app. Again, the launcher is not something the user can "exit ... from recent apps" as it's not a standard app. It's the root / home / base app. You don't "exit" it, unless you switch to a different launcher app. So if the user "exits" the launcher app with a password ... where do they go?

yes, my bad, I got confused, so if the use clicks the recent button from navigation bar, I can see the recent apps, settings app for example, I was able to go to the settings of the phone, also if user swipes down, the user will be able to access settings thru that, that is what I want to prevent,

Using Neptune SDK/PAX SDK
private IDAL iDalService = null;

//Initialize SDK
try {

            iDalService = NeptuneLiteUser.getInstance().getDal(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Class Name", "Error initializing Neptune SDK, message: " + e.getMessage());
        }

public void hideBars() {

        if (iDalService != null) {
            //Disable Navigation bar.
            iDalService.getSys().enableNavigationBar(false);
            //Disable Status bar.
            iDalService.getSys().enableStatusBar(false);
            //Hide Navigation bar.
            iDalService.getSys().showNavigationBar(false);
            //Hide Status bar.
            iDalService.getSys().enableStatusBar(false);
        }
    }


You can use this method to show/hide those functionality
private fun setLockTask(start: Boolean) {
    try {
        if (start) {
            startLockTask()
        } else {
            stopLockTask()
        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

For Disable -
setLockTask(true)
For Enable -
setLockTask(false)
I hope this help you to resolve this issue.
